# How to push a value into a multi-dimensional array (RUBY)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm looking to push the value 1 into an array of all 0's at a random index point.
The format of the array is a 10 by 10 lot of 0's arranged into a square table. I want to generate a random input point for this, and change that value to 1.

Comment: Are you sure "push" is the word you're looking for? "Push" has a very specific meaning, i.e. to add an element to the end of an array. It sounds like you just want to change an element in the array, which is not "pushing."

Comment: Ruby doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays (unless you count `Matrix` from the standard library), Ruby has arrays-of-arrays. The solution should be pretty simple if you understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below :-

```
# First create an array of array
array = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) { 0 } }

# method to get the random index.
def random_index(start_point = 0, end_point)
  (start_point..end_point).to_a.sample
end

# First find out the any random inner array
inner_array = array[random_index(0, array.size-1)]
# Then get the any random index from the inner array and update the value.
inner_array[random_index(0, array.size-1)] = 1
array
# => [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

To answer the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489493/how-to-push-a-value-into-a-multi-dimensional-array-ruby/27489647?noredirect=1#comment43411842_27489647) :-

```
def get_index_of_item_from_inner_array(array, item)
  first_inner_array_contains_item = array.find { |in_ary| in_ary.include? item }
  (0..first_inner_array_contains_item.size - 1).find { |ind| first_inner_array_contains_item[ind] == item }
end

get_index_of_item_from_inner_array(array, 1) # => 2
```

Comment: Thanks mate this is exactly what I was after, how would you know what the index is of the 1 though? Like if I wanted to find it later?

Comment: @Danny12345 Didn't get you :)

Comment: How would I find the index point of the 1, like for your example it's in the 10th column of the 2nd row, ie coordinates 10,2.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
arr = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) { 0 } }

row, col = rand(100).divmod(10)
arr[row][col] = 1

row #=> 7
col #=> 6
arr
  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```